# Foreign key is NULL in ASP.NET in 1 to many relationship. How do I add it in controller?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a 1 to many relationship between my recipe table and AspNet user table, but I end up with NULL as my foreign key whenever I create a new recipe.
`public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }` is in my **Recipe model** and
 `public List<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }` is in my **ApplicationUser model**

[Recipes table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLl55.png) after i've added some test recipes in **DbInitializer**. Row 3 was created through localhost and the foreign key is NULL.

```
  foreach (var u in db.Users.Include(b => b.Recipes) )
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                u.Recipes.Add(new Recipe
                {
                    Title = $"{i}",
                    Introduction =  $"{i}",
                    Ingredients =  $"{i}",
                    Instructions =  $"{i}", 
                    Nutrients =  $"{i}"
                    
                });
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
```

I just can't figure out how to set the foreign key in the **Controller** for when I create a new recipe :

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,Introduction,Ingredients,Instructions,Nutrients")] Recipe recipe)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(recipe);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(recipe);
    }
```

Sorry if my post is messy, this is the first time I've posted here.

EDIT: I'm uncertain but is this what you asked for? I would access user id by just typing in user.Id right?

```
   public class RecipesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public RecipesController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

EDIT 2: Thanks for the help, the code correctly assigned a foreign key now.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,Introduction,Ingredients,Instructions,Nutrients")] Recipe recipe)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Adding the foreign key to recipes
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            recipe.UserId = user.Id;
            
            _context.Add(recipe);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(recipe);
    }
```

Comment: You need to assign the Id or User object, if the client isn't going to pass it in, then you have to do it in the `Create` method body. Show us your code on how to retrieve the user Id and we can show you how to assign it

Comment: I've edited it but, I don't know if thats correct. Thats the code that is also in the controller. Would I just write "var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);" Then user.Id in the create body?

Comment: Essentially yes, but to be definitive when we post questions about EF relationships you should post the whole class definition of the `Recipe` along with the fluent configuration if you have any. If you are using attribute notation then there might not be any fluent to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, I personally assign audit info inside the `DbContext.SaveChanges()` method, but that's a global approach that's out of scope for this post.

At a fundamental level you need to assign the user before you call `SaveChanges()` so the following code might work in your case:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,Introduction,Ingredients,Instructions,Nutrients")] Recipe recipe)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // assign the user
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        recipe.ApplicationUser = user;

        _context.Add(recipe);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(recipe);
}
```

> **NOTE:** This is just a guide, in some cases the above assignment may not work, especially if your `UserManager` does not use the save `DbContext` *instance*. In such a case you will find it simpler to assign the user using the *Foreign Key*, not the navigation property.